# python sqlite3. Executemany вводит слово в таблицу по буквам

Tags: python, sqlite3

Ситуация следующая. Я сделал простую таблицу, в которой есть два столбца - id и cat (category).

Пользователь вводит слово cat, после чего слово помещается в таблицу.

Проблема - слово помещается в таблице не целиком, а по буквам.

```
input_text = input()
first_word = re.findall(r'\w+', input_text)[0]
two_word = re.findall(r'\w+', input_text)[1]

if first_word == 'new':
        if two_word == 'cat':
            new_category = re.findall(r'\w+', input_text)[2]
            cur.executemany("INSERT INTO category (cat) VALUES(?);", new_category)
            print("Вы создали новую категорию - " + new_category)
```

И результат следующий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. "new cat medicina" создает новую категорию.
all cat - выводит все категории.

Как я ожидал, результат должен быть таким:

> **[(1, 'medicina')]**

Надеюсь, я правильно разъяснил свой вопрос. Пожалуйста, помогите чем можете.

Comment: `cur.executemany(..., (new_category,))`.

Comment: комментарий Михаила Муругова не помог, к сожалению.

Comment: Да, потому что я не обратил внимание, что там `executemany`, а не `execute`. Тогда `cur.executemany(..., ((new_category,),))`.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение, хоть и через костыль.
Раз программа считает new_category множеством букв, то я решил объеденить всё это с помощью join. И вместо executemany сделал execute.

```
new_category = re.findall(r'\w+', input_text)[2]
my_list = [''.join(new_category)]
cur.execute("INSERT INTO category (cat) VALUES ( ? );", my_list)
print("Вы создали новую категорию - " + new_category)
```

По итогу нужный результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]